# Kaggle tutorial explanation

Tags: python, function, recursion, call

```
def mult_by_five(x):
return 5 \* x

def call(fn, arg):
"""Call fn on arg"""
return fn(arg)

def squared_call(fn, arg):
"""Call fn on the result of calling fn on arg"""
return fn(fn(arg))

print(
call(mult_by_five, 1),
squared_call(mult_by_five, 1),
sep='\\n', # '\\n' is the newline character - it starts a new line
)
```

This is from the python tutorial in Kaggle. I don't understand how its working out. The explanation is even more complicated. Also, the blacked lines appeared when I copied them here. Any idea how I remove it?

I have been trying to break it down to step by step working but got stuck.

Comment: Please edit your question and place `code` in code blocks.

Comment: first you have to put code with correct indentations - at this moment code has wrong indentations and it is useless.

Comment: you can always split to smaller parts - ie. assign result from function before you send to another funtion - and use `print()` to see what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. OR you can learn how to use real debuger  - but it can be simpler to put code in https://pythontutor.com/ and run it line by line (like in debuger).

Comment: in python you can use function's name without `()` as value and assign to variable or send to function - and later you can use `()` to execute this function - ie. `show = print` (without `()`) and later execute `show("Hello World")` and it will execute `print("Hello World")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but you can use `print()` to display all variables and results and see how code works.

```
def mult_by_five(x):
    print('\n--- start: mult_by_five ---')
    print('[mult_by_five] x:', x)
    result = 5 * x
    print('[mult_by_five] 5 * x:', result)
    print('--- end: mult_by_five ---\n')
    return result

def call(fn, arg):
    """Call fn on arg"""
    print('\n--- start: call ---')
    print('[call] fn:', fn)
    print('[call] arg:', arg)
    result = fn(arg)
    print('[call] fn(arg):', result)
    print('--- end: call ---\n')
    return result

def squared_call(fn, arg):
    """Call fn on the result of calling fn on arg"""
    print('\n--- start: squared_call ---')
    print('[squared_call] fn:', fn)
    print('[squared_call] arg:', arg)
    result1 = fn(arg)
    print('[squared_call] fn(arg):', result1)
    result2 = fn(result1)
    print('[squared_call] fn(fn(arg)):', result2)
    print('--- end: squared_call ---\n')
    return result2

# --- main ---

print('--- start: main ---')
print('[main] mult_by_five:', mult_by_five)
result1 = call(mult_by_five, 1)
print('[main] call(mult_by_five, 1):', result1)
result2 = squared_call(mult_by_five, 1)
print('[main] squared_call(mult_by_five, 1):', result2)
print('--- results ---')

print(result1, result2, sep='\n') # '\n' is the newline character - it starts a new line
print('--- end: main ---')
```

Result:

```
--- start: main ---
[main] mult_by_five: <function mult_by_five at 0x7f28f6c368b0>

--- start: call ---
[call] fn: <function mult_by_five at 0x7f28f6c368b0>
[call] arg: 1

--- start: mult_by_five ---
[mult_by_five] x: 1
[mult_by_five] 5 * x: 5
--- end: mult_by_five ---

[call] fn(arg): 5
--- end: call ---

[main] call(mult_by_five, 1): 5

--- start: squared_call ---
[squared_call] fn: <function mult_by_five at 0x7f28f6c368b0>
[squared_call] arg: 1

--- start: mult_by_five ---
[mult_by_five] x: 1
[mult_by_five] 5 * x: 5
--- end: mult_by_five ---

[squared_call] fn(arg): 5

--- start: mult_by_five ---
[mult_by_five] x: 5
[mult_by_five] 5 * x: 25
--- end: mult_by_five ---

[squared_call] fn(fn(arg)): 25
--- end: squared_call ---

[main] squared_call(mult_by_five, 1): 25
--- results ---
5
25
--- end: main ---
```

Eventually you can put original code in https://pythontutor.com/ and run it line-by-line and it will also shows what is in variables. So it works like real debuger.